# Using Cloudflare as a proxy prevents cookies being stored in browser

Tags: flask, cloudflare, flask-wtforms

I'll attach an image to illustrate what I'm looking to do:

[image]

***Note: The above photo should say "Redirect to HTTPS"***

***To preface, this is the following is the technology stack***

- DNS: GoDaddy
- Proxy: Cloudflare
- Client: React app hosted on Heroku
- Server: Flask API hosted on Heroku

The flow at least to my understanding is this:

1. User enters in `domain.com` in browser and GoDaddy forwards all traffic to Cloudflare so that the site is viewed securely
2. Cloudflare then forwards the traffic to where the client is hosted
3. Once client is loaded, it makes a request to the server to receive a CSRF token. The CSRF token is generated by a method within `flask-wtf`. A session is created in the server and in the response, the CSRF token is attached to the header

***Here things gets weird***

Since the response received on the client never had the CSRF token attached to the header and no cookie was set on the browser, I would assume that the response goes to Cloudflare before the response hits the client. As a result, the CSRF token is never received. Not sure why this is the case.. But after a bit of research, I've discovered that Cloudflare does this by default.

It seems that a work around would be to use Cloudflare Workers, but that seems only available if their DNS is being used. Ideally, I would like to stick with GoDaddy.

I was wondering if anyone else experienced this and found a different solution.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "It seems that a work around would be to use Cloudflare Workers, but that seems only available if their DNS is being used" Unless you are paying for the expensive enterprise Cloudflare account, you have to be using Cloudflare as your DNS server. GoDaddy may be your DNS registrar, but if you are using it for more than DNS registration then you aren't actually using Cloudflare at all. That could be part of your problem.

Comment: Also, by default Cloudflare won't be stripping CSRF token headers from responses, you would have to configure some sort of response rewrite rule or something to make that happen in Cloudflare.

Comment: @MarkB Hi, you brought up some interesting points. I'm a bit new to building out entire infrastructure for projects, so I appreciate everything you mentioned. In regards to GoDaddy, yes the domain is registered with them. The reason for using Cloudflare was due to the fact that GoDaddy doesn't have a feature to forward traffic to secure versions of the site. Given that situation, would I be using Cloudflare as a DNS unknowingly?

Comment: Probably? it would be pretty easy to login to your Cloudflare console, look at the DNS tab, and see if you have records in there that you are using. You could also use a tool like [this](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) to check who is resolving your DNS records for you. Also, to be fair, Cloudflare's DNS services are WAY better than GoDaddy's, so I highly suggest using that instead of GoDaddy anyway.

Comment: @MarkB Based on your link, NS, which I presume stands for name server would indicate who is the DNS provider?